# Horizontal Submenu needs to stretch 100%

Tags: submenu, stretch

So I'm trying to implement a nav with a horizontal submenu that I found on [CodePen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FbvZ.jpg) but I'm having trouble getting the submenu to stretch 100% of the nav-wrap. If I give it a width of 100% it inherits the width in the parent element unless I give it a width in pixels, which I obviously don't want to do.

My css is a bit bloated due to the fact that I'm trying to incorporate the codepen project within my current project. I've deleted all unnecessary code except for what's in the css in case I'm missing something.

This is roughly what I'm trying to achieve. It's important that the nav stays uniform.

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/

```
body {
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 67.5% or 65.7% */
}

#wrapper {
    width:85%;
    height:85%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#nav-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  font-size:2.7em;
  font-family: 'allgemeineregular', Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width:14%;
  min-width:140px !important;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height:1.1em;
}

.orange {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f37028;
}

.orange p {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.orange a span /* added when link has more than one word */ {
    display:block;
}

.orange a:link, .orange a:visited { 
    padding:0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.orange a:hover { 
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#231f20;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

li .subnav-orange {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color:#f37028;
  font-size:0.25em;
  text-align:left !important; 
}

.subnav-orange ul li a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.subnav-orange ul li a:hover { 
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover > .subnav-orange {
 display:inline-block; 
 left:0;}

.subnav-orange ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  float:left;
  padding:10px 0;
  width:100%;
}

.subnav-orange ul li {
    width:14%;
    margin: 0 10% 0 0 !important;
}

<div id="wrapper">

  <ul id="nav-wrap">

    <li id="link-one">

    <div class="orange"><a href="#" class="parent-one-link"><span>Digital</span><span>Printing</span></a></div>

    <div class="subnav-orange">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.subnav -->
    </li>


  </ul>

  </div> <!-- wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/1/

there is plenty of `css` adjustments

Comment: Minus the bit of padding, that's exactly what I need. Thank you. I won't ask you to go through all the css that was changed but was there something in particular that stood out?

Comment: The width in .orange changed from 14% to 140px but I'm going to need that link as a percentage. A fixed width definitely won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: This is essentially what I'm trying to create. It's important that the links stay uniform. http://imgur.com/hZe0Fb9

Comment: I put .orange's width back to 100% and then the width in ul li controls all. Seems to do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/9m6Kn/4/

Comment: use the same percentage for the top boxes as for the sub-menu